# Programmatic default value for Sequelize model

Tags: sequelize.js

How can I create a default value that is generated programmatically upon creation of a new instance of a Sequelize model?  I've read how to do this somewhere, but can't find it anywhere.  I thought this had something to do with `classMethods`, but I can't figure out what that method should be called.

For example:

```
sequelize.define('Account', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING
}, {
  classMethods: {
    something: function (instance) {
      instance.name = 'account12345';
    }
  }
});

models.account.create(function (account) {
  console.log(account.name); // Echos "account12345" or whatever I
});
```

If you could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can just define defaultValue as function, sequelizejs explained in http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/datatypes/, the example code is

```
sequelize.define('model', {
  uuid: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: function() {
      return generateMyId()
    },
    primaryKey: true
  }
})
```

However, you can't get the instance because before the defaultValue generated we don't have the instance.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer you have to make sure it's unique by yourself.

Comment: @cattail How about if I'm adding a column, therefore the instance is already available. Can I get set the value of a different column as the `defaultValue`?